# how to check session exist in spring_session table in spring session?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-session

I have implemented Spring session in my spring MVC project and it is working fine. The configuration classes are follows.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 60)
public class SessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }
}

public class SessionInitializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

}
```

I have used HeaderHttpSessionStrategy, so that it will add 'x-auth-token' in the response headers.
It is successfully adding the 'x-auth-token' header in the response while logging in (I am creating a session in java in login controller method).

```
x-auth-token : ee97ea13-9264-423a-aed7-3be72d330566
```

But i want to create a filter class, so that i can check all the other subsequent REST calls are having the 'x-auth-token' header. How to create such filter? Filter has to compare the session id which is available in the 'spring_session' in database.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why? That is basically the purpose of Spring Security/Spring Session. Why add this yourself? If the header isn't there, the user isn't authenticated and will not get access (as the authentication info is stored in the session). Unless you are using something else for that as well.

Comment: It is not happening in my case. Authentication is not getting stored in the session. While logging in, i am creating a session by myself and logging out and invalidating the session. So i am getting x-auth-token in login response's header. It between the authentication is not getting store in session. I guess that is my issue. is there any configuration that i need to do? spring security allowing requests without x-auth-token header.

Comment: Which is how the session works. If you logout the session is destroyed, what else do you think logging out it for>?